# Mysql time format Y-m-d H:i:s isn't working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table ts with a timestamp field, that will have data inserted after following calculation:

From the data source I got:
$date = $ts[$s]['datetime']; // "2018-06-03T07:00:00.000Z"
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));  // "2018-06-03 07:00:00"

Every 10 minutes $timestamp (and other data) will be inserted into the mysql table ts.

A php program should select the last 6 entries. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM ts WHERE (now() - t_timestamp)<3600000 ORDER BY t_timestamp ASC;
```

If I try different values (for the milliseconds) like 3600000, 1800000, 600000 ...  gives me ALL data of the table, not just the expected last 6, 3, 1 rows.
However, 81000 gives me the last row,
82000 gives me the last 2 rows,
83000 gives me the last 3 rows,
84000 gives me the last 4 rows,
85000 gives me the last 5 rows

That was before the hour, now it starts again with:
81000 gives me the last row,
82000 gives me the last 2 rows,
...

It seems it only displays the 1,2,3,4,5,6 lines of the last hour.

I tried another way and it gives me zero lines:
    SELECT * FROM ts WHERE t_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY t_timestamp ASC;

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hint: SELECT now() - t_timestamp FROM ts ORDER BY t_timestamp DESC limit 6; Are you sure you see the difference in milliseconds?

Comment: To be clear, you may need to add the output of DESCRIBE ts.

Comment: LIMIT 6 indeed makes the list up to 6 rows, but not over the hour. The other suggestion SELECT now() - t_timestamp FROM ts ORDER BY t_timestamp DESC limit 6; is interesting, it spits out 6times the t_timestamp of 80450 out. Something I don't understand, but with my observation that 81000 lists one row and 82000 two rows, ....  it might have a meaning.

Comment: I suggested the limit 6 only for testing, to see the list of differences. The other suggestion was to tell more information about the table structure, mostly the type of ts column and mysql version cause the behaviour of now() - sometype may differ.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper | field t_timestamp is of the datatype timestamp

Comment: I think I found something. The data are inserted as UTC, but my server is on GMT+800. Therefore SELECT * FROM ts WHERE t_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY t_timestamp ASC; showed nothing, but with 9 HOUR, it does show data. I added in my php program the line: date_default_timezone_set ('UTC');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174108/discussion-between-ronald-wiplinger-and-n3ko).